# In Git-Bash-Windows `openssl pkcs12` does not prompt for password

Tags: windows, openssl, git-bash, pkcs#12

The SSL certificate authority sent me the signed certificate in `.pfx` format and it was password-protected; so I need to convert it to `.crt` file.

The first attempt was to call `openssl pkcs12 -in server.pfx -out server.crt -nokeys -clcerts`, simply in Git-Bash Windows; but it waits forever, and there was no output nor hint. Eventually, I switched to Linux (RHEL7), and the same command worked OK. It turns out, in Linux the command prompts "`Enter Import Password:`"; however, running in Windows Git-Bash the it's missing the prompt for password, and will be hanging there forever.

I'm wondering if there is anything to make it work in Windows Git-Bash, e.g. command argument, etc., as my work computer is still running Windows OS. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

**Screenshot of Linux:**

```
[root@host]# openssl pkcs12 -in server.pfx -out server.crt -nokeys -clcerts
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
[root@host]#
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, on Windows 10, you could switch to any Linus distro of your choice through WSL2.

Second, on Windows, I always had to include the password in the command line:

```
openssl pkcs12 -password pass:aPassword -in server.keystore.pfx -nokeys -clcerts -out server.cert
# or
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:aPassword -in server.keystore.pfx -nokeys -clcerts -out server.cert
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @VonC, and it works. I've tried `-password pass:aPassword` and `-passin pass:aPassword`, and either one works.

Comment: By the way, I've just tried WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) Ubuntu, and it works as well. Thank you again for this hint.

Answer (score 15):

On Git-Bash, you have to use winpty in front; e.g.,

```
$ winpty openssl pkcs12 -in server.keystore.pfx -nokeys -clcerts -out server.cert
```

Comment: this works! also if you have the openssl command inside a bash script, I run the script adding "winpty" prefix : 

winpty bash myscript.sh --parameters ....

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how - After a whole day of thinking. You may refer to this link for the explanation https://omgdebugging.com/2019/03/17/openssl-hanging-up-when-trying-to-convert-certificates/

*"This issue arises because in the difference how input is passed to the OpenSSL command by Git Bash console. The fix to this issue is adding the word `winpty` before the entire command. Doing this will make the prompt enter your password, confirm the password again and once done, you will notice that a PFX file has been generated."*