# Where to generate next auth secret for next auth

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt

The documentation for NextAuth.js says that I can generate a secret for next auth by entering this command:

openssl rand -base64 32

Here is the documentation: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_secret

However, when I enter the command in the terminal within VS code I get this error.  [image: Error given in VS code when I run the command in file path: PS C:\nextjs\Amazon-starter-template-nextjs>]

I'm trying to run this command on Windows.

Answer (score 16):

Just use Bash terminal in VS code. You can create new terminal: [image]

And then choose Bash:
[image]

And just run script in Bash

PS: You can have multiple terminals open at once which is helpful sometimes

Comment: From the screenshot: `openssl rand -base64 32`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a few months old but I still want to answer the question.

Its because by default OpenSSL is not installed onto Windows machines, the command doesn't work on CMD or Powershell.

Git Bash comes with OpenSSL and hence the command will work on Git Bash which is why it'll work if you open it on VS code like in Grayza's answer.

**EDIT**: I have just discovered today that you might also need to add `winpty` before the `openssl` command in Git Bash. Found through this post [In Git-Bash-Windows `openssl pkcs12` does not prompt for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275008/in-git-bash-windows-openssl-pkcs12-does-not-prompt-for-password)

If you do have it installed on your machine then it might not be in your system's environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

Paste this in your Vscode terminal or Gitbash or whichever terminal you are using:

```
npx auth secret
```

Then make sure you add the new secret to your `.env` file:

```
AUTH_SECRET="put your auto generated secret";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vercel for your hosting, you can generate a secret at https://generate-secret.vercel.app/32

Comment: You can use that for any hosting.