`openssl` command hangs when trying to create keystore.key
openssl command hangs when trying to create keystore.key
This is the command I run in Git bash:
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out keystore.key

I can see that the keystore.key fine gets created but it's 0KB and the command appears to hang. I tried adding -password pass: password but that give this error:

Mac verify error: invalid password?

What am I doing wrong?

Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275008/in-git-bash-windows-openssl-pkcs12-does-not-prompt-for-password (and several more)

@dave_thompson_085 Your Google-fu is better than mine, although there is a chance this isn't a Windows system given the paucity of information.

@AndrewHenle: no google; I've seen those several similar Qs over the years and after noticing the pattern I bookmarked them. I think Windows is a pretty safe bet: only on Windows (without WSL or similar) is it necessary to choose 'git bash' or 'git cmd'; on *nix you use git by itself and it isn't related at all to openssl. And only on mintty do you get the problem with password prompt/input.

Per OpenSSL the passphrase-options man page:

OPTIONS
Pass Phrase Option Arguments
Pass phrase arguments can be formatted as follows.
pass:password

The actual password is password. Since the password is visible to
utilities (like 'ps' under Unix) this form should only be used where
security is not important.

Note there is no space between the pass: and the actual password:
pass:password
openssl ... -password pass: password ... would be the equivalent of passing an empty password followed by password as another command-line argument.
